# How to insert multiple values in a table with an equal second cell

Tags: mysql, sql

I have s MySQL database and I need to insert some specific data in a table. The data should be as follows:
**SELECT id FROM a_table WHERE ...** returns me a list of ids.
I need to insert **n** rows in **second_table** where **n** is the count of the returned rows from the first query. The second table requires 2 fields - The first one will be a record from the first query and the second one will be an integer, that I will pass from my script.
For example: If the first query returns **(12,14,17,18)** and the integer from my script is 5 I need to create a query, that will insert **(12,5),(14,5),(17,5),(18,5)** and I need this done in the database layer - I don't want to create a select statement, then create a query and then run it.
I need something like this (this is not a real query - It just shows what I need):

**INSERT INTO second_table (user_id,group_id) VALUES ((12,14,17,18),5)**

or to be more precise like this:

**INSERT INTO second_table (user_id,group_id) VALUES ((SELECT id FROM a_table WHERE ...),5)**

Is there a way to do this in SQL only (no tsql - sql only)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can include a literal value in a SELECT:

```
INSERT INTO second_table (user_id, group_id)
SELECT id, 5
FROM a_table
WHERE ...
```

Comment: This was the thing I was looking for. Thank you.
P.S: will accept the answer in 8 minutes

Comment: @ДамянСтанчев: You can use arbitrary expressions in a SELECT (given column availability of course) and `5` is an expression. And `INSERT ... SELECT` only needs the number of columns and their types to match up.

Answer (score 1):

```
INSERT INTO 
    second_table 
       (
       user_id
       ,group_id
       ) 
SELECT
    id
    ,5
FROM
    first_table
WHERE
    ...
```

see the MySQL docs for more details on INSERT...SELECT syntax:

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-select.html

Answer (score 1):

Hi you can try  query given below

Insert into items select item_sold_qty , 5 from sales

```
INSERT INTO second_table 
SELECT id , 5 FROM a_table  WHERE ...
```

thanks